# How to arrange positioning of Qr code using Zxing in c#

Tags: c#, zxing.net

How to arrange positioning of qr code for a label printing.?.I have tried this code.How to get the qr code at the middle of label?

```
        Encoding m_encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1");
        byte[] dataFromFile = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(op1.FileName);
        string txt = m_encoding.GetString(dataFromFile);
        int tt = txt.Length;

        BarcodeWriter writer = new BarcodeWriter
        {
            Format = BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE,
            Options = new EncodingOptions
            {
                Width = 50,
                Height = 50
               // Margin = 1

            }
```